# Setting up gmail alaises / groups to be used with Outlook desktop

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, gmail, google-workspace, microsoft-outlook-2011

We use Outlook 2011 (mac) as the desktop client for some of our machines, the actual emails are running on Gmail (Google apps for business) which we connect to via `imap`.

We have individual accounts set up for each user, but we also have aliases or groups which are things like `info@`, `support@` etc which get forwarded to all the users associated with those groups / aliases.

Is there a way to configure Outlook to allow you to also send from these aliases / groups ?

Comment: "Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks" are [off topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic) here, you could try [sf].

Comment: @terdon - thanks but its actually to do with configuring an account in the outlook desktop client, rather than anything server / network based.